# Get webpage content from requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

am trying to build a scrape but cannot get hmtl content, at first I was getting 403 error and I included headers to the code . How can I get the webpage content. here is the  the code:

```
url = 'https://www.devex.com/organizations/search'
headers = {
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
org_soup = soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(response.content.decode())
```

Here is the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RO-uZrphYo70SamHsVeCGBhOTnU8X01j#scrollTo=UESDXIH4ehW1)

Here is the task:
This platform lists 77,000+ organizations on its website. We would like you to acquire the data against all of these organizations. The search page for the directory is available here: ( https://www.devex.com/organizations/search ). When you select into any organization, the internal page will present information such as the below: (https://www.devex.com/organizations/environmental-resources-management-erm-21485). Please generate a scrape that captures at least the following information from the internal tabs

1st Tab - Organizational Information

- Company Name
- Company Logo
- Company Description
- Organization Type
- Staff
- Development Budget
- Headquarters
- Founded
- website link

Sectors, comma separated in one column

Funded, comma separated in one column

Countries, comma separated in one column

Skills, comma separated in one column

2nd Tab - Contracts

- Use the Company Name as the unique identifier
- Contract Name,
- Contract Fundier, e.g. Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation

Comment: Check the response, there is a captcha. Improve your question with some more details, expected output, ... so answers could be more specific and help with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a language to the headers:

```
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
```